What are the prerequisite to learn operating systems?
I am self learning operating systems. I am facing difficulty to grasp the ideas of where libraries and memory are present in a hardware . So what are the prerequisites to learn operating systems ?

You'll need a good understanding of a computer's architecture. Keywords like memory, I/O, CPU, physical address, virtual address, just to name a few.

This question is similar to: What operating system concepts should I be fluent with to understand LVM in UNIX operating systems?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
